# Assessing an UML class diagram

Tags: uml, associations, multiple-inheritance, class-diagram, class-design

Suppose I draw an UML class diagram representing the class and interface structure of my project. Are there any methods to assess the UML design before actually creating those classes and interfaces?

Example: It is known that the diagram below will lead to diamond problem. And must be changed or handled.

[image]

Comment: You model says that any `Domestic Animal` is both a `Cat` **and** a `Dog`. That doesn't seem valid in my world.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I showed the picture to exemplify my question. It may not be that accurate as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML is a powerful design language.  It is programming language independent (although it has a bias towards class based languages) and thus allows to design things that are not implementable in some languages but trivial in some other languages.

The real question is what you expect from assessment:

- **syntactic and semantic validity** of the model with regard to its compliance with the UML specifications?  In your diagram, you use `void` type, which does not belong to the primitive types of UML. It's a language dependent type.
- **completeness and accuracy** of the model, with an eye on potential ambiguities and missing informations?  In your diagram, `Animal.eats()` may for example be `{abstract}`. But is the absence of this information an indication that it's not abstract ?
- **evaluation of the class design**, such as for example its complexity, the deepness of the inheritance, the intensity of relations, mutual dependencies, etc... ?  But how can this help to spot a bad design, when some domains are just inheriently complex ?
- **feasibility**?  [UML allows for multiple inheritance](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams), but does not precisely define the semantics behind it.  For instance, in C++ you can very well cope with this design with the [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) of `Animal`. In Java, multiple inheritance is forbidden and this would not be implementable as such (you would need to alter this model to introduce an interface and use [interface realization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/realization.html#interface-realization)).  Now here, we will not reopen the [debate about MI](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#multiple).

A systematic review of of diagrams is done here everyday.  The goal of such assessment is to see if the notation is consistent with the UML specification, and eventually with the constraints of the chosen [UML profile](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile.html). There are some [research papers](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4301193) that explore the automation of such consistency assessments.

Design is currently not highly automated;  There is therefore no systematic method to assess the design as far as I know.

There are some general metrics (e.g. [CK metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_complexity#Chidamber_and_Kemerer_Metrics)) and some of these can be [calculated for UML](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_11/article1/) class diagrams (e.g. only 3 out of 6 CK metrics for example). Metrics are not assessments, but they can help an analyst in this task.